# Laravel validator mimes rule not working for documents

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to upload document files as pdf, doc, docx. To make i'm using this values:

```
$mimes = [
      'doc' => [
        'application/msword',
        'application/vnd.ms-office'
      ],
      'docx' => [
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
      ],
      'pdf' => [
        'application/pdf',
        'application/x-pdf'
      ],
    ];
```

> output: string(150) "application/msword,application/vnd.ms-office,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/pdf,application/x-pdf"

After file upload, i had mime rule fail for any types.

So, i do this test:

```
$input = [
  'document' => $document // UploadedFile instance
];

$clientMime = $document->getClientMimeType() // output @example  application/pdf

$rules = [
  'document' => 'mimes:' . $clientMime;
];

$validator = Validator::make( $input, $rules );

$validator->fails()->errors() // mime fail
```

**OTHER TEST**

Uploading a .jpg file (for example) the mime rule works

```
$rules = [
  'document' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg';
];

$validator = Validator::make( $input, $rules ); // all right
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-mimes), you use it like this:

```
'document' => 'mimes:pdf,doc'
```

Try this, and it should work:

```
$clientMime = $document->getClientMimeType() // output @example  application/pdf

$rules = [
  'document' => 'mimes:pdf';
];

$validator = Validator::make( $input, $rules );
```

Comment: A great confusion around mimes and extensions. Solved, thanks!